# Using only native PHP function to get array values from a list array inside an array

Tags: php

I have an array below:

```
$arr = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'ABC'
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'CDF'
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'GHI'
    )
)
```

How can I convert to just with native function in PHP:

```
$arr = array( 'ABC', 'CDF', 'GHI');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$arr = array_map('current', $arr);
```

Comment: Just in case one of the arrays pointer has been moved past the first element, I believe you can use `reset` instead of `current`, but the idea is the same.

Comment: @David That doesn't actually matter, the arrays passed to the `current` callback have their pointers reset.

Comment: Is that because they are passed by copy to the callback or some magic provided by `array_map`?

Comment: @David Yes. ;) (I.e. I can't say for sure, but I suspect copy.)

Answer (score 0):

```
function flatten($input) {
    $output = array()
    foreach($input as $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $output = array_merge($output, flatten($value));
        } else {
            $output[] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $arr = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'ABC'
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'CDF'
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'GHI'
    )
);


function MultiDimensionToSingleDimension($array, $index='name') {
     $return = array();

     if (is_array($array)) {
        foreach ($array as $row) {
             $return[] = $row[$index];
        }
     }

     return $return;
}
print_r(MultiDimensionToSingleDimension($arr));
?>
```